# How can I modify an element based on ancestor "has"?

Tags: css

```css
.grid-container {
   background-color: yellow;
}

.grid-container:has(.someClass1) {
   background-color: red;
}

.grid-container:has(.someClass2) {
   background-color: green;
}

/* NEEDS TO VARY BETWEEN CONDITIONS: 
   default -> border: 5px solid grey;
   .grid-container:has(.someClass1) -> border: 5px solid black;
   .grid-container:has(.someClass2) -> border: 5px solid blue;
*/
.thirdElement {
   border: 5px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
   <div>
     <div>
        <div class="someClass2">Marker 2</div>
     </div>
   </div>
   
   <div>
      <div>
         <div class="thirdElement">
            Unrelated element under .grid-container
         </div>
   
 </div>
```

It's easy to modify a particular element if it `:has` something in its hierarchy, e.g.

```
.grid-container:has(.specialClass1) {
    
}
.grid-container:has(.specialClass2) {
    
}
```

But now I need to modify an unrelated element, `.thirdElement`, somewhere under `.grid-container` and which has no relation to `.specialClass2`, based on the ancestral `.grid-container:has` condition above. There is no sibling or other relationship between `.thirdElement` and `.specialClass[X]`. The only thing they have in common is they're both descendants of `.grid-container` somewhere.

So what I need to do is

```
.thirdElement CONDITION-TRUE: .grid-container:has(.specialClass1) {
   /* .. */
}
.thirdElement CONDITION-TRUE: .grid-container:has(.specialClass2) {
   /* .. */
}
```

If the general condition of `.grid-container:has(..)` is TRUE, then I need to apply certain tweaks to `.thirdElement`. Is that possible?

Quick snippet that shows this with colors is attached

Comment: Please don't tag your titles, especially by awkwardly slapping them on the front. See [ask].

Comment: Can you post your HTML and create a runable snippet so we're not guessing at structure based on a text explanation?

Comment: Yes, snippet posted, but the answer below worked for me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not following what you're trying to convey with `CONDITION TRUE`, but this might be what you're looking for:

```
.grid-container:has(.specialClass1) .thirdElement { ... }
```

This will style all `.thirdElement` elements that are children of a `.grid-container` element that contains a `.specialClass1` element.

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be as simple as:

```
.grid-container:has(.specialClass1) .thirdElement {}
.grid-container:has(.specialClass2) .thirdElement {}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked - simple condition on child with space.